# Is filteredDestination faster than JMS selectors in ActiveMQ?

Tags: performance, jms, activemq-classic

I'm almost sure that I have read that [filtered virtual destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) in ActiveMQ are more efficient than it would be to use the same selectors on the client side in the subscription. However, I have searched for some hard data or official advice and I can't find it.

There are some rather old posts about issues with selectors, for example [Ade on Middleware](http://trenaman.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/message-selectors-and-activemq.html), but they seem to have been solved according to the ActiveMQ JIRA. I have seen nothing recent.

So, my question is if filteredDestination is more efficient than a normal message selector would be and (if so) why?

Answer (score 1):

I would not look at filtered destinations as "an optimized version of client selector". Filtered destinations are administered by the broker administrator and client ones are dynamically added and controlled by the clients. Well, one of them likely will be faster in a given scenario. I would suggest you choose to filter where you want to have the maintenance of this filter done (broker XML or client code). If performance is really important, I suggest you measure some more specific conditions as I assume the result may vary depending on a lot of case specific details.

Comment: That wasn't really my question. I want to know how it works and if there are cases where filtered destinations are likely (not guaranteed) to outperform selectors. If I had the time I could dig into the code or run extensive tests, but I'm short on time and I'm curious. Perhaps there is no general rule, but if there is perhaps one of the experts out there will enlighten us!